# Adding Multiple Objects in Unity ARKit

Tags: unity-game-engine, arkit

I want a user to place multiple objects in a room (like the IKEA app). I'm using Unity3D ARKit plugin. Currently, when I tap the screen, a new object is placed where I tap and the previous object is destroyed. How can I keep every object in the scene after I add them?